# As a convert woman married to a Catholic with no legal separation, how can I marry a Muslim man?

Tags: nikah, non-muslim

I was married from Catholic religion but separated without legal procedure. I converted to Islam about 8 month ago. I've had a Muslim boyfriend for almost 2 and half years, and we want our relation to be Halal: We want to get Married.

What can you advice me, because as I read some of your articles here, there is no scenario like mine.

Comment: Does your BF has access to an Imam or Masjid who can guide you both in this matter. Your situation requires professional guidance and not this forum :) Good Luck Sister!

Comment: If you accepted islam, then from a shariah point of view you would be regarded as divorced after idah by traditional scholars. But you might be legally a bigamist in a non-muslim country! And scholars would recommend to take local laws and costums into account!

Answer (score 1):

[IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=332842) explains that the marriage between a Muslim woman and a non-Muslim man is Islamically invalid:

> If he refuses to embrace Islam and remains a non-Muslim, then you should know that your marriage to him has become invalid from the day that you embraced Islam. If he did not convert to Islam within your 'Iddah (waiting period after divorce), then it is impermissible for you to remain with him. Rather, you must leave him.

Converting to Islam 8 months ago also means your [iddah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iddah) would be finished.

However, there are practical complications of being legally married to one man and Islamically married to another man, such as [anti-bigamy laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigamy) and matters of inheritance.

Also note that "Muslim boyfriend" refers to a kind of relationship that's not appropriate in Islam ([Dar Al-Ifta](http://www.dar-alifta.org/Foreign/ViewFatwa.aspx?ID=10757)).